# How can I make this regex code more efficient?

Tags: python, regex

I am removing legal forms from company names, and my approach is to use a regular expression to match the legal forms. The code looks like this:

```
    syn = [re.sub(r'\b' + form + r'\b', '', name).strip()
           for form in self.forms
           if re.search(r'\b' + form + r'\b', name)]
```

However this is quite slow as there are several hundred legal forms. Is there a better way?

Comment: This question looks better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IanAuld How do I migrate?

Comment: I believe a mod will need to do that

Comment: I don't think Code Review will like this question unless you can provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). They're not inclined to improve code unless they can run it on their own machines.

Comment: @Kevin on CR we expect the whole code, in context, not just a minimal example

Comment: Instead of the loop, make your regexp like `\b(form1|form2|form3|...)\b` and remove them all in one shot.

Comment: You can use `join` to comcatenate all the forms with `|` between them.

Comment: @Barmar if there are many forms it will result in error.`OverflowError regular expression code size limit exceeded`

Comment: Then do them in groups.

Comment: I went with compiling them beforehand instead of in the loop. Improved speed by like 50x. I may try the group idea later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should precompile your regex since have a large number of them. Python memoizes regexes by default, but your large number will exceed the cache size.

Another option may be to tokenize the company string since it is probably not long. Then check each token against a `set` containing your forms. Then join the tokens at the end.

```
self.forms = (...)
tokens = company.split(' ')
return ' '.join([ t for t in tokens if t not in self.forms ])
```

Comment: That won't work, the legal forms consist of multiple words, so splitting on whitespace doesn't help. Anyway, since precompiling the regexes did the trick, I will accept this answer.